# Connect Snowflake from AWS Athena using Spark engine

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-athena

In the AWS Re:Invent 2022 it was announced new functionalities for Athena, including run data analytics and exploration using Apache Spark without the need to plan for, configure, or manage resources. However I wonder if it is possible or has anyone tried to connect to snowflake using these pyspark notebooks? I know that using Athena SQL engine I can do it, but I want to know using Spark engine.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, it is not possible to connect to Snowflake using Athena's PySpark notebooks.